# Members Database - Show All?

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm not the best with PHP but everyone has to start somewhere.

I am wondering how I would go about taking all of the rows from a database, taking out the data from a certain column and outputting it in a certain way.

The reason I'm doing this is to make it show up with all the users registered on one page, sort of like a members page any forums would have.

I was thinking of somehow fetching the rows than putting the data into arrays than doing a foreach statement to print it out as each variable.

I'm not the best logical thinker but I will give a bit of database information below :)

This is an image of the structure of the database.

[image]

To show you guys that I am actually putting an effort into this, this is what I got so far with my terrible PHP skills ;)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $username=array($row['username']);
    $email=array($row['email']);
    $firstname=array($row['firstname']);
    $lastname=array($row['lastname']);
    $motto=array($row['motto']);
    $bio=array($row['bio']);
}
foreach ($username as &$item) {
    print $item;
}
```

The one reason this code wouldn't work is because than its just selecting a row of the person with the id that is equal to $userid. This means it would grab the row info, not the column info.

Not sure how to do this as I've only done stuff with rows so far in my PHP adventure, not so much with columns :(

Comment: Why not just `SELECT * FROM users` then?

Comment: But how would I put the data for all users in say $username then be able to echo it onto a page listing each one. Just a foreach statement but how would I style it for example it would show Picture, Username than the motto next to the username like that? It would be pretty hard.

Comment: @KevinHarrison You should read a PHP/MySQL/HTML tutorial. This site is for specific questions.

Comment: This is most definitely a specific question. As I clearly said how would I be able to take this data and the second part to the question was asking if I were to use a foreach statement to echo each user in the array, would that be a good idea or is there a better way. I'm sorry if my question was a bit unclear as maybe there was some miscommunication but hopefully this clears it up for you :)

Comment: @KevinHarrison It's some HTML and a loop, **very simple** once you have learnt it. Update your question with your attempt.

Comment: I tried again using the information AlexP provided me and this is what I got. Sadly this only shows 1 person, not ever user in the array. Although I tested printing just $username with print_r to test whats in the array and it also showed up with only 1 user when theres about 30. Now this means the mistake is somewhere in fetching the data, I'm thinking this has to do with where I do mysql_fetch_array($result). Any help? D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is, each time you loop through using "while", you have a new set of information.  Just display your stuff right there.  It's way easier than you think, which is why you have commenters complaining.

But DON'T use the mysql_* functions.  Use mysqli or PDO.  I know that there are tons of examples out there using mysql_*, but that's because they're either old examples or bad ones.  Don't use it.  I have taken an [example from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) and adjusted it for you.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY username");
if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $username=$row['username'];
        $email=$row['email'];
        $firstname=$row['firstname'];
        $lastname=$row['lastname'];
        $motto=$row['motto'];
        $bio=$row['bio'];

        //display your row of user information here
        echo "<div>";
        echo $username;  //etc.

        echo "</div>";
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! It actually worked! And yeah, I heard a lot of people saying to use Mysqli so now that I'm still a beginner I should jump on that so I dont go down the wrong path :) Thankyou!

Comment: I just got one more quick question that is part of this. If I wanted to display $email also, would I have to change it from where it is ORDER BY username? Because if I try to echo anything besides username right now it comes out with random characters and doesnt even show the username.

Comment: No, you should be able to echo any of the columns.  "ORDER BY username" just gives you the list in alphabetical order by user name.  No idea what could be giving you random characters -- wait, check your text encoding.  Is it in some weird other language, or does it say UTF-8 or unicode or something like that?

Comment: latin1_swedish_ci is the collation but the username prints out fine, I'm guessing this collation makes it jumble the letters together because I see an @ symbol for email in each.

Comment: You should probably do some trial-and-error with changing to general unicode encoding and enforcing UTF-8 on your page, and fiddling with your HTML.  If you can't figure it out after a while, post another question.